# System of symmetric quadratic equations

Tags: quadratic-forms

Suppose $A_1, A_2, \ldots A_k$ are real symmetric (but possibly singular or indefinite) matrices. I want to know whether the system of quadratic equations
$$v^T A_i v =0 $$
has a nontrivial solution for $v$.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: look through the information on Elimination Theory.  It might help.